# How do I analyse a set of SQL Profiler-generated rolling trace files?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, profiler

I am trying to diagnose an issue with a production SQL Server instance. I have asked the DBA to provide a trace and have been given a set of SQL trace files (1185 files to be precise).

When I open the first file, SQL Profiler detects presence of additional trace files and prompts me to load the **one by one** - this approach does not scale to 1185 files.

Ultimately, what I want is to import all that trace data into SQL server so I can query it.

Can you recommend an approach or tool that would allow me to do this?

Comment: do you have dev sql server instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Laerte Junior has a nice article on how to read these using Powershell](http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/fun-with-sql-server-profiler-trace-files-and-powershell/).  Go down to the "Reading Multiple Trace Files and Insert into SQL table." section for the exact statement.

Answer (score 5):

The following will insert the entire set of files into a table of your choosing. Then you can query. Please do this on a dev instance.

```
SELECT * 
INTO [Database].[schema].[table] 
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable('\path\to\tracefile1.trc', default)
```